# Sunrise versus "Summon Eclipse" in Buffy the Vampire Slayer

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

The Sunrise rule states:

> When the talisman moves to the Sunrise, all vampires that are outside must immediately move to the closest indoor space.

The "Summon Eclipse" card states:

> Move the Phase Talisman to the first New Moon space.

If the Talisman has to move *past* the Sunrise space to get to the first New Moon space, does this trigger Sunrise?

I say, "No", since you're moving the Talisman *to* the first New Moon space (effectively skipping over the Sunrise space), but others in our group insist it does in fact trigger "Sunrise", since they argue you move the Talisman forward (and through Sunrise) to the first New Moon space.

Comment: No need to be so defensive! :)

Comment: Is this for [Buffy the Vampire Slayer: The Game](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/805/buffy-vampire-slayer-game) or [Buffy the Vampire Slayer: The Board Game](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/7822/buffy-vampire-slayer-board-game)? To make things more confusing, both were published in 2000 by different companies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going off of this [version of the rules](https://www.orderofgamers.com/downloads/Buffy_v1.2.pdf).

> If the Sunrise space is moved past in
> one turn, these effects still take
> place.

It sounds like the token always advances, and passing through the Sunrise space is sufficient to trigger the vampire actions.

Comment: I guess I look at it more as "Go directly to Jail, do not pass Go, do not collect $200" sense of "Move the talisman to the first new space".  I guess for my interpretation to work, it would have to say something like "Place the Talisman on the first new space" or explicitly state that sunrise is ignored.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Its definitely not clear cut, but this is the way I read the rules coming to the game cold.  I suppose if it horribly unbalances the game you can make a case for the alternative.